# inquiry about installing ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

if I were to install Ubuntu, replacing windows 10 altogether, would this action make all my previous downloaded programs that supported win10 be rendered "useless" ? like Spotify, jing, portableapps and a dozen more programs.

Comment: Yes. If you remove W10, all downloaded programs will be removed with it, or will not work on Ubuntu. Generally, programs for Windows expect Windows, not another OS.

Comment: I feared that would be the response, cheers. many of the downloaded programs are "paid" versions...and I don't want to give them up.

Answer (score 1):

Most people take their time to familiarize with Ubuntu by having both systems installed or by using a secondary PC. Most people never switch fully to Ubuntu as they have a couple applications which they just need to use and they are not compatible with Ubuntu.
Some applications are also released for Ubuntu (i.e. Spotify runs just fine). Some others are not but they can be run with wine (windows emulator). Some others just need to run on Windows and you will not manage to get them running on Ubuntu.
I would recommend you take it one step at a time, with dual boot or second Ubuntu machine. Familiarize with the system, try to run your applications, see what runs and what fails. Finally weigh the benefits of each operating system and which applications are critical for you and which you can live without.

Comment: iam not very tech savvy imho. I would need to carefully weigh my options here. ive been facing a lot of glitches ever since the anniversary update.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility if you just want to 'try out' Ubuntu is to boot your computer using an Ubuntu 'live CD'. Your computer will run as an Ubuntu system without changing your Windows 10 installation, and without removing any of your installed Windows programs.

You'll find an explanation of this option [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD).

Comment: good, thx a lot